# "A service is listening on all interfaces" - explanation needed?

Tags: networking, docker, telegraf

We got a security report, and one of the points was that a service is listening on all interfaces.

I am not a security guy and I find it hard to understand what needs to be done and how to do it.

The "service" is telegraf agent running in a docker container:

```
netstat -nlpt | grep 9273
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9273            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

Obvious it can accept communication on all interfaces of the machine, however it gathers info only locally.

How do I restrict it?

By doing the following:

```
docker create --name telegraf -p 127.0.0.1:9277:9273 telegraf:1.18.3
```

I also change this bit in telegraf's config:

```
# Telegraf pull metrics configuration
[[outputs.prometheus_client]]
   ## Address to listen on
   listen = "localhost:9273"
```

I couldn't make it not to have `0.0.0.0:*` in the output of the `netstat` command

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps when you are doing `docker create --name telegraf -p 127.0.0.1:9277:9273 telegraf:1.18.3` it listens on `127.0.0.1:9277` and on `0.0.0.0:9273` because you have not specified any address for the `:9273` port part?